# Можно ли реализовать композицию в Rust с помощью анонимных структур?

Tags: ооп, rust

Я пишу на Rust компилятор, который описан в книге дракона на Java. Пока что написал только лексический анализатор. Там есть класс Token, у которого есть дети Word, Num, Real. В свою очередь у класса Word есть ребёнок Type, у которого есть ребёнок Array.

Каким образом у меня в данный момент это реализовано на Rust:

```
pub struct TokenBase {
    tag: u32,
}

pub struct WordBase {
    token: TokenBase,
    lexeme: String,
}

// ...

pub enum Word {
    Word(WordBase),
    Type(TypeBase),
}

pub enum Token {
    Token(TokenBase),
    Word(Word),
    //...
}
```

В Rust ассоциированное значение варианта перечисления можно определить в виде анонимной структуры:

```
pub enum Token {
    Token {
        tag: u32,
    },
//...
```

но как тогда определять структуры для потомков ? И можно ли вообще это сделать ?

Comment: У вас тут нет никаких потомков, в rust вообще нельзя наследовать от реализации, только от интерфейсов (которые обзывают трейтами) . То бишь `extends` как в Java запрещен, можно только только `implements`, причем только неявно.

Comment: @user7860670, я знаю. Вы думаете я только сегодня узнал про существование такого замечательного языка программирования ? Вопрос "как тогда определять структуры для потомков" означает как определить ассоциированную с вариантом Token::Word структуру, чтоб она имела в качестве поля анонимную структуру, ассоциированную с вариантом Token::Token

Comment: @Антон, ты что-то очень странное пытаешься сделать: естественным решением ИМХО было бы определить типаж `Token` и реализовать его для `Word`/`Num`/`Real` итд...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Структуры для потомков (ассоциированных значений вариантов Word::Word, Word::Type) в таком случае определить не получится.